# Secondary axis scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Yes, I know you "shouldn't" use a secondary scale because it's "not correct" but my tutor still wants this two graph to be in the same plot and I need to add a secondary scale... I managed to write the code, but the problem comes when I need to define the new scale. I need to add 50 to the values of the primary one and then divide everything by .15 like here

```
P <- ggplot(data=dd)+
  geom_line(aes(x=dS, y=(nS*.15)-50), color="blue3", size=.25)+
  geom_line(aes(x=dO, y=cO), color="red", size=.25)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = dd$dS[dd$Year %% 5 == 0], color="black", linetype="dashed", size=.25)+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(([~. +50] / 0.15), name = "nss Sulphate (ppb)"), limits=c(-50,-20))+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="Depth (m)", y=expression(paste(delta^{18}, "O (‰)")))
P
```

but I get an error of "non-numeric argument to binary operator". I tried different kind of parenthesis but nothing really seems to work.

Any ideas?

edit:
dummy dataset

```
dS<-c(1:100)
dO<-c(1:100)
nO<-runif(100, min=-36, max=-25)
nS<-runif(100, min=0, max=150)
Year<-c(1900:2000)
dd<-data.frame(dS,dO,nO,nS,Year)
```

Comment: Where is `dd` in your question?

Comment: dd is the dataset I'm using but I can't share it because are data that are yet to be published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess for this line `y = nS` because there is no `cO`. To solve this error use `(~./0.15 +50/0.15)`.

This should work.

```
dS<-c(1:100)
dO<-c(1:100)
nO<-runif(100, min=-36, max=-25)
nS<-runif(100, min=0, max=150)
Year<-c(1900:1999) #df does not have the same number of observations.
dd<-data.frame(dS,dO,nO,nS,Year)

P <- ggplot(data=dd)+
  geom_line(aes(x=dS, y=(nS*.15)-50), color="blue3", size=.25)+
  geom_line(aes(x=dO, y=nS), color="red", size=.25)+ #y = nS
  geom_vline(xintercept = dd$dS[dd$Year %% 5 == 0], color="black", linetype="dashed", size=.25)+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis((((~./0.15 +50/0.15))), name = "nss Sulphate (ppb)"), limits=c(-50,-20))+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="Depth (m)", y=expression(paste(delta^{18}, "O (‰)")))
P
```